# How to call Confirm dialog on IML?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've just started to use IMl (http://incframework.com/). Does anybody know how to call confirm dialog on IML?
I mean confirm function from JavaScript.

```
function conf(){
    confirm('text')
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use confirm on conditional

```
 @(Html.When(JqueryBind.Click)
       .OnSuccess(dsl =>
                  { 
          dsl.Self().Core().JQuery.Attributes.AddClass("progress-success")
             .If(r => r.Is(() => !Selector.JS.Confirm("Yes or No")));           
                   } )
       .AsHtmlAttributes()
       .ToButton("Are you sure ?"))
```

Please look at [sandbox](http://incframework.com/en-US/TutorialConditional#Confirm)

Also if use Break with OnBegin you can stop multiple executable.

```
.OnBegin(dsl => dsl.Core().Break.If(r => r.Is(() => !Selector.JS.Confirm("Yes or No")))
.OnSuccess(dsl => { // something code })
```

Answer (score 1):

:) Please take a look at this resource -  http://incframework.com/en-US/TutorialConditional#Confirm